# C double pointers malloc

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers, and trying to define a structure as follows.

| header info (size_t) | pointer to cstring |

here is part of the code. I type defined string as char**.

```
string str_constructor(const char* const str)
{
    size_t* header = (size_t*)(malloc(sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(char**)));
    char** data = (char**)(header + 1); //data is now the address of the pointer to cstring
    *data = (char*)(malloc(strlen(str) + 1)); // plus one char for null character
    for (int i = 0; i != strlen(str); i++)
    {
        *data[i] = str[i]; // cstring deep copy
    }
    *header = strlen(str); // store length of string
    *data[*header] = '\0'; // append null character
    return data;
}
```

The program crashed on 2nd iteration of the for-loop.

Basically I want to define a string, where *string would return the char*.

Comment: How could `char** data = (char*)(...` ever work?

Comment: right, sry typo, but the code still doesn't work, crashes the same way.

Comment: Have you tried `(*data)[i] = ...` ?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general!

Comment: @MikeNakis thanks, it works now! can you submit an answer?

Comment: [please read this to tell you why you should not cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: thank you for the info @EdHeal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a highly unorthodox way of creating a structure in memory, but if, as you say, you want to understand pointers, then who are we to tell you to do it differently?

The only *real* problem with the code you posted is that `*data[i] = ...` should be `(*data)[i] = ...`.

That having been said, you might want to consider that your way of creating a structure in memory ignores the native alignment of the CPU, which means that you are bound to get sub-optimal performance.  Declaring a `struct` would have taken care of that.  On some architectures (not x86 luckily) your program may even crash if it attempts to make a non properly aligned memory access.

Comment: I see. I am actually building this function for micro processors, specifically stm32. I suppose I have to ensure it is 8-byte alligned?

Comment: I know nothing of the stm32.  I have never even heard of it before.  If the 32 in the name means 32-bit, then you will probably be fine with 4-byte alignment, which is most probably what you get with `header + 1`. 
 However, a) You should read up on it, or b) just try it and see if it works, or c) just play it safe and let the compiler take care of alignment for you so that you do not have to worry about it.  I would read up on it and *still* play it safe.

Answer (score 2):

The lines look unusual

```
size_t* header = (size_t*)(malloc(sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(char*)));
char** data = (char*)(header + 1); //data is now the address of the 
                                     pointer to cstring
```

Why cast the return to `size_t*`? Why double pointer `char **`?

I would try something like

```
struct info {size_t size; char * string};

struct info * p = malloc(sizeof *p);
p->size = strlen(str) + 1;
p->string = strdup(str);
```